# C# unmanaged Export of an Array to Fortran

Tags: c#, arrays, fortran, unmanaged, managed

In the following I used [Robert Giesecke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/35443/robert-giesecke)'s template to make unmanaged dlls.
I tried sucessfully to pass a value from C# to Fortran with following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using RGiesecke.DllExport;

namespace AddDll
{
    class MyAddDll
    {
        [DllExport("Add", CallingConvention = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static int Add(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }
    }
}
```

On the Fortran side:

```
MODULE MYEXTERNALS
USE iso_c_binding
INTERFACE
FUNCTION Add(a,b) RESULT(ret) bind(c, name="Add")
USE, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
INTEGER(c_int), VALUE, intent(in) :: a,b
INTEGER(c_int) :: ret
END FUNCTION
END INTERFACE
END MODULE MYEXTERNALS


PROGRAM CallAdd
USE MYEXTERNALS
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER a, b
a = 4
b = 3
PRINT*, 'a + b =', Add(a, b)
PAUSE
END PROGRAM CallAdd
```

that works fine!
Now I would like to pass an array with following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using RGiesecke.DllExport;

namespace AddDll
{
    class MyAddDll
    {

        [DllExport("Arr", CallingConvention = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static void Arr(int [] a)
        {
            a[0] = 1;
            a[1] = 2;

        }
    }
}
```

On the Fortran side:

```
MODULE MYEXTERNALS
USE iso_c_binding
INTERFACE
FUNCTION Arr(a) RESULT(ret) bind(c, name="Arr")
USE, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
INTEGER(c_int), intent(in) :: a(2)
INTEGER(c_int) :: ret
END FUNCTION
END INTERFACE
END MODULE MYEXTERNALS


PROGRAM CallArray
USE MYEXTERNALS
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER a(2)
PRINT*, Arr(a)
PAUSE
END PROGRAM CallArray
```

that gives me the error:
[image]

Can anyone help me, to pass an array from C# to Fortran?

Comment: The exception code it displays, 0x4f4d, is the low 16 bits of 0xe0434f4d, the exception code of a managed exception.  Many possible reasons, you are blind as a bat to .NET exceptions when you use Gieseke's tool.  Debugging this with a managed debugger would be wise, you can diagnose the simple stuff like "file not found".  The return value type is wrong, but that doesn't normally bomb.  Maybe you need `ref` on the argument.

Answer (score 2):

Your C# code defines a `void` function, which corresponds to a FORTRAN `subroutine`. As such, it doesn't have a return value, and you are meant to `call` it.
The following should work, I think:

```
MODULE MYEXTERNALS
USE iso_c_binding
INTERFACE
SUBROUTINE Arr(a) bind(c, name="Arr")
USE, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
INTEGER(c_int), intent(in) :: a(2)
!INTEGER(c_int) :: ret
END SUBROUTINE
END INTERFACE
END MODULE MYEXTERNALS


PROGRAM CallArray
USE MYEXTERNALS
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER a(2)
call Arr(a)
print*,a
!PAUSE
END PROGRAM CallArray
```